# Azure add inbound rule via sdk

Tags: python, azure, sdk

I am trying to get the azure sdk to add a inbound rule

```
t = network_client.network_security_groups.begin_create_or_update(
        resource_group_name,
        security_rule_name,
        {
            "access": "Allow",
            "description": "New Test security rule",
            "destination_address_prefix": "*",
            "destination_port_range": port,
            "direction": "Inbound",
            "priority": 400,
            "protocol": "Tcp",
            "source_address_prefix": ip,
            "source_port_range": port,
        },
    ).result()
```

Unfortunately whatever I find on the web or on here is out of dated and this doesnt seems to work saying it is out of scope.

Did anyone actually succefully add a rule using the sdk?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the `security_rule_parameters` property. Look at the [sample in the SDK to create an NSG](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/network/azure-mgmt-network/generated_samples/network_security_group_rule_create.py).

```py
t = network_client.network_security_groups.begin_create_or_update(
        resource_group_name,
        security_rule_name,
        security_rule_parameters={
            "properties": {
                "access": "Allow",
                "description": "New Test security rule",
                "destination_address_prefix": "*",
                "destination_port_range": port,
                "direction": "Inbound",
                "priority": 400,
                "protocol": "Tcp",
                "source_address_prefix": ip,
                "source_port_range": port,
            }
        },
    ).result()
```